# How to update a particular row of SharePoint list using c#

Tags: development

I have a SharePoint list with around 20 columns. The list contains some rows.Once the person pressed the save button of my window form , the data will be saved the List and a new entry will be created in the same SharePoint list. Now I want to update a particular entry again without creating the new row using C#. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

This you can Acheive using SharePoint Server Object Model and Client Object Model ,

for example using SharePoint Client Object Model you can update the particular list item using below code snippet :

```
 string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");

        ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
        oListItem["Title"] = "My New Item!";
        oListItem["Body"] = "Hello World!";

        oListItem.Update();

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

so once the item is created you can retrieve the created item using its id as follows :

```
        ListItem oListItemUpdate = oList.Items.GetById(oListItem.Id);

        oListItemUpdate["Title"] = "My Updated Title.";

        oListItemUpdate.Update();

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you , but i don't know the particular row where i need top update. How to search the particular row?

Comment: yes that you can get the particular item using its item ID , like explained above if immediately the item need to be updated once its created it can be done like this oListItem.Id , otherwise if you know the item ID it can be specified explicitly like oList.Items.GetById(5)  ;

Comment: But i have around 44 columns in my List and the updation will be done by user through  form which is created in visual studio using c#. So i don't know which row and which column will get updated. I think i need to replace the whole row with the newly entered data. In this case, does the GetItembyId will work?

Comment: first you need to be clear about the item need to be updated , here you need to filter the items either by retrieving the single item by using GetById() method , or if you need multiple items need to be updated you can use CamlQuery to retrieve the items . and while updating the item it's not like you need to update all the columns values , for what are all the columns you're assigning the values only those columns will be updated without disturbing other column values

Comment: But The column which is getting updated is not fixed

Comment: that we need to handle in the code as per requirements applying conditions .

Comment: I don't know , how to write the code for this requirement. Simply i am understanding it can be done by ID.

Comment: refer this  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx will help you

Comment: I implemented the above code , but now i am getting the following exception: One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields(Server Exception Unhandled ).

Comment: Please check the internal name of the columns you've used in the coding ,,, this error is thrown when there is a mismatch in the column name used in the coding and the internal name of the column in the list